# Running a batch file (with blanks) from powershell script

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I need to call a batch file from powershell script. The batch file name will be decided using the parameters to PS file from user. I have this code but not working as expected. Could someone poing me my mistake? Everything seems fine but I am getting issues with the actual batch file calling (one of the last 4 statements)

```
param(
  [string]$parts
)
$sharedDrive = "\\server\share"
$cred = get-credential "DOMAIN\"
$username = $cred.UserName
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$net = New-Object -com WScript.Network
$net.mapnetworkdrive("", $sharedDrive, "true", $username, $password)

$BatchFilePath = $sharedDrive + "\Public\Upgrade\Application Folder"
IF ($parts -eq "P1") {
    $selectedBatchFile = "`"" + $BatchFilePath + "\P1 Upgrade File.bat" + "`""
} ELSEIF ($parts -eq "P2") {
    $selectedBatchFile = "`"" + $BatchFilePath + "\P1P2 Upgrade File.bat" + "`""
} ELSE {
     Write-Host "Invalid Part specified. Choose one from: P1, P2"
}

$command1 =  "/k $selectedBatchFile   $username   $password"

## I tried all the below but NONE worked

#& cmd "`"$command1`""
#& cmd "$command1"

#Start-Process "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "$command1"
#Start-Process "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "`"$command1`""
```

Comment: I've used [Invoke-CmdScript](http://poshcode.org/2176) to call batch files, with params, from powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to start it with cmd.exe /k?

```
start-process -filepath $selectedbatchfile -argumentlist $username,$password
```

Comment: It did work Thank you.
    start-process -Wait -NoNewWindow -filepath cmd -argumentlist "/c", $selectedbatchfile, $username, $password

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Invoke-Expression "cmd /k `"$selectedBatchFile`" $username $password"
```

NOTE: I do not normally suggest using Invoke-Expression if it executes code from text that a user has input.  For instance, think about what happens if you use Read-Host to ask the user for their username and they type in `; Remove-Item C:\ -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction 0;`.  Yeah, that might be a bad day for you.

On V3/V4 you could also use `--%` but it requires storing your info in env vars which you might not want to do with a password:

```
$env:file = $selectedBatchFile
$env:un = $username
$env:pw = $password
cmd.exe /c --% "%file%" %un% %pw%
```

See this [post for more details on --%](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/).

Comment: I couldnt use the env solution. First one did not work.

Comment: If you can, I highly recommend updating to at least V3 (V4 is currently the latest).  Calling exes with parameters has been a major source of frustration and was at least partially addressed by the `--%` operator in V3.